# Delay while searching data with SQLite and put on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, sqlite, uisearchbar

I have a screen with **UITableView** and a search bar. This search is made in the database, it must also look at another related table and so do some *inner joins*.

The problem is that there is a delay while I type fast, because when I finish typing a word I see the **UITableView** is updated slow letter by letter until complete the search with the whole word.

Here is a piece of code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue new] autorelease];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(makeSearch:) object:searchText];

    [self.queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}

- (void)makeSearch:(NSString *)_string {
    [self.displayItems removeAllObjects];

    Users *usr = [[[Users alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.displayItems = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[usr getUsersLike:_string]] autorelease];

    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

(The variable `displayItems` use to populate the **UITableView**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cancel pending operations on your queue before adding a new operation when `textDidChange`, otherwise you have to wait for each individual search to complete before the most recent one can execute.